# DESCRIPTION_LIST in tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

How does this work? If I specify an address list, I know I can specify a load balance or failover option to switch the connection to the other address.

But in case of various descriptors (DESCRIPTION {...}) what's happening? Is it a random choice from the connector?

Answer (score 2):

Which Database Version do you have?

From Oracle 11g onward you should be using the SCAN listener. The SCAN listener knows where the database is located in the RAC and how much load is on that node.

Further more you should define services for long ops and short ops for better load balancing.

Comment: Our configuration is for failing over a standby database using a different service name, so we cannot use the scan listener. But thanks for the idea though, it made me think of something else

Comment: Why not? If you have a primary RAC and a standby RAC you can configure the tnsname.ora to use both scan listeners with failover options. In case the standby is a single instance just use the scan listener for primary and the standard listener for standby.

Comment: we use the scan listener for node a to node b in primary rac and in secondary rac with no issue. Failover=on. The problem comes when I have to fail rac1 over rac2: it has to be separate "DESCRIPTION{}" groups because the service names are different.

Comment: What is your setup? I understand your configuration like this: Do have a primary RAC and a standby RAC. One database on the primary RAC has a "DataGuard Standby Database" on the standby RAC. Is this correct?

Comment: yes exactly. Each rac is a 2 nodes rac.

Comment: OK. I guess you configured the primary service name to something like "orclp" and the standby to "orcls". But when you switch over/fail over the service name does not. Correct? If yes, you can switch the service name with a startup trigger.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, what you describe is indeed our scenario. I read about the startup trigger. I will keep it in mind in the future, but so far we found the description_list to be a good and less intrusive alternative. What do you think?

Comment: The advantage of the scan listener is that all connections to the RAC go through a single process. This improves load balancing and connection time. For example you have a 6 node RAC and a database runs on only 2 nodes. The worst case would be 4 connection attempts fail before you find the db instance. In a two node RAC this does not make such a difference. But remember you have 4 nodes and the database you are looking for runs on 2 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This (old) Oracle document [67137.1 Load Balancing and DESCRIPTION_LISTs](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=67137.1)<sup>1</sup>  says the following about the effects of multiple `DESCRIPTION` elements:

> When SQL*Net reads a TNS alias with a DESCRIPTION_LIST, it flips a coin to 
>   select which description to use to connect.  This randomization is what 
>   provides us with our Load Balancing feature.

It further says that if the randomly-chosen connection fails, then it randomly selects again between the remaining descriptions.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Oracle support account required</sub>